# How is the hash for a file calculated?

Tags: hash, sha-256, sha-2

Is the file just read bit by bit to calculate the hash with those values or is there more to it?

Are there any resources to read a bit more about file hashing?

Comment: The question is only loosely related to cryptography. Crypto algorithms work on binary data, how the data is stored before it's submitted as input to a hash algo - in a file, in a memory buffer or otherwise - is irrelevant. Programming questions are better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: @tum_ Idk, I think it doesn't really fit into either of them but i felt like this here was a little bit better suited...

Comment: Well, to be honest, it is still not clear what *exactly* you are looking for. So, now that you have the feedback, you might consider editing your question and be more specific,

Comment: What is unclear about it? What do i need to give to the alg to get the file hash.

Comment: The file content. What makes you think there should be anything else? )

Comment: It looks like you're right. Apparently the metadata has no influence on the hash. My apologies.

Comment: Well, you just have to remember that files are made of bits. And you know how to hash bits.

Comment: I do, but when I change the filename (From testfile.txt to testfil3.txt) the hash doesn't change. Not in my implementation and not [here](https://md5file.com/calculator) or [here](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256_checksum.html). I guess sometimes things are less complicated than I imagine them to be...

Comment: Yeah, *now* it's finally clear what you were after. I can't name any off the top of my head but I can imagine certain crypto applications built **on top of SHA-2** where the metadata would be involved. But sha-1,2,3 on its own just processes a bit string.

Comment: What you hash (file content, file name, file metadata such as timestamps) is dependent on the applications needs. Without knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish, it's not possible to answer the question of "what should I hash".

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything in particular, I just want to implement SHA256 and i thought that there was a standard for how to hash files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hash functions operate on blocks like SHA-256 has 512-**bit** input block. In SHA-256, your data $m$ is divided into 512-bits blocks $m_1,\ldots,m_n$ where each entered into the hash function. The final block, $m_n$ is padded as

$$k=(447−l) \bmod 512$$ where data size is $l$ and $k$ is the number of zeros following the 1 after $m$ and finally the message size in 64 bits. The message size can also 128 which allows larger files to be hashed. So the input to SHA-256 is

$$m\|1\|0\ldots0\|\text{size_of(m)}.$$

Each other hash function defined in a similar way, an example from [RFC4634](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4634#page-6)

> The hash functions specified herein are used to compute a message
> digest for a message or data file that is provided as input.  The
> message or data file should be considered to be a bit string.  The
> length of the message is the number of bits in the message (the empty
> message has length 0).  If the number of bits in a message is a
> multiple of 8, for compactness we can represent the message in hex.
> The purpose of message padding is to make the total length of a
> padded message a multiple of 512 for SHA-224 and SHA-256 or a
> multiple of 1024 for SHA-384 and SHA-512.

**Note:** The 64-bit (or 128-bit) message size also determines the maximum input size for a SHA-256 hash.

Comment: So it's just the file in binary?

Comment: Always. What you else you expect?

Comment: Idk that's why I asked the question.

Comment: The block size depending on the hash function. As said SHA-1 512-**bits**

Comment: I'm aware. And this question is about SHA256, which is part of the SHA-2 family, but the block size is also 512 bits.

Comment: I'll verify if your answer is correct. If so, i will accept the answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: if you can verify the answer how come you didn't discover the answer yourself? :-)

Comment: I wrote an implementation of sha256, it works for manual input and i want to add file hashing. For that, it would be helpful to know where to start.

Comment: The RFC4634 explains in details, and you can find test vector at [Nist](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-algorithm-validation-program/secure-hashing#sha-2)

Comment: As in the answer, your messaage $m$ is the input file, you read it into 512 bit to enter the hash function...

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. File hashing is a way of creating a `unique identifier` for a specific input with incredibly low chance of collision. A collision happens when two inputs map to the same output. So far we have not seen any cases of collision for SHA256 or SHA3; two of the most prominent hashing algorithms. In terms of what goes on inside a hashing algorithm, its not just mapping one bit to another bit. There can be different methods including (but not limited to) bit substitution, logical operations, and many other bitwise operations. A good hashing algorithm should be complex enough that two very similar inputs map to very different outputs, again making it a `unique identifier`.

For example:
`SHA256(0000000) = ABD4562B6AEE9F`
`SHA256(0000001) = 255FBA9C5C33ED`

Comment: Just to clearify, I know how sha256 works. I just need to know what to put inside of it to get the hash for a file. Also, isn't SHA-3 a family of algorithms? Anyways, i'm sorry but I don't really see an answer to my question in your answer.... Thanks anyways.

Comment: It's "collision", not "collusion"

Comment: @b3nj4m1n Yes, SHA-3 is a family of algorithms, but Ronald is still correct in saying that we haven't seen any collisions for any of the SHA-3 hashes.